# Given $f:\mathbb{R}^m \supset U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ differential. Relation of rank of $f'$ and the property of image of $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m \supset U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a differential map, $U$ open, and $a \in U$. Are the followings true:

1. If $m > n$ and $f(U)$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\text{rank}f'_a = n$?
2. If $m < n$ and $\pi\big(f(U)\big)$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (with $\pi:f(U)\ni x=(x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto (x_1,...,x_m)\in \mathbb{R}^m$), then $\text{rank}f'_a = m$?

I don't know how to get information on Jacobian of $f$ to know about its rank. I tried  a proof by contradiction as follows:

In 1's problem, If $\text{rank}f'_a = k < n$ then $f'(a):\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$. We have, when $h\rightarrow 0$, $\mathbb{R}^n \ni f(a + h) - f(a)\rightarrow f'_a(h)\in \mathbb{R}^k$. But, I don't see any reason to forbid $f(a + h) - f(a)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ close to a point $\mathbb{R}^k$. So may be the conclusions are wrong.

If they are wrong, could you give a counterexample? And under which conditions they're right?

Edit: the more general question of the two questions: is the following true:

If $\pi\big(f(U)\big)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^k$ (with $\pi:f(U)\ni x=(x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto (x_1,...,x_k)\in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $k\le\min\{m,n\}$), then $\text{rank}f'_a = k$?

If it's wrong, give a counterexample. And, under which conditions it's right?

Partly answer: The counterexample of the first claim is provide in the Amirhossein's answer; generalize this counterexample, we get the counterexample of more general question is the map
$\mathbb{R}^m\ni (x_1,...,x_m)\mapsto (f_1(x)=x _{1}^{3} +...+ x _{m}^{3},...,f_k(x)=x _{1}^{3} +...+ x _{m}^{3}, f _{k+1}(x)=0,...,f _{n}(x)=0)$ they all has rank $=0$ at $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

So, the remain question is: Under which conditions the claims is true?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no for both of them:

For the first claim:

Consider the the function $f: \Bbb R ^{2} \to \Bbb R, \hspace{0.2cm} f(x,y) = x^{3}.$

Clearly a smooth function with $f(\Bbb R ^{2}) = \Bbb R$ which is open. but $f^{\prime}_{(0,0)} =(0,0)$.

And your second claim can not occur because $f(U)$ is of measure zero in $\Bbb R^{n}$. So it cannot be an open set.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of second claim. And in the case $f$ is smooth linear map, the second claim is true. Why $f(U)$ is measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Could go further details. By the way, I add extra question about extra condition to the claims true when they're wrong. Check my edited question.

Comment: What I used for the second claim is the well-known Sard's theorem. and it is easy to see that an open set has a measure greater than zero. In the case of linear function, again the image is not an open set.

Comment: sorry if this confusing is silly. Consider map $i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2: x \mapsto (x,0)$, it's linear, it's smooth map and its derivative is itself, its jacobian is $\binom{1}{0}$ has rank 1. I search and use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem#Statement, applying to this map, it said $f(U)$ has Lebesgue measure 0 in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $U$ still open in $\mathbb{R}$, and I don't see any contradiction with $\text{rank}f'_a=1$.

Comment: I found another counter example for second question, they're maps $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $t \mapsto (at^k+b,ct^l+d),~a,b,c,d,k,l$ are constants $k,l \in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $\ge 2$, their derivative has rank $0$ at point $0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Here again $f(\Bbb R)$ is not open in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: But the requirement of second claim is $f(U)$ open in $\mathbb{R}^m$ **not** in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in this example, $f(\mathbb{R})$ still open in $\mathbb{R}$, with natural inherited topology, of course.

Comment: It does not have meaning unless you say how you will identify $f(U)$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^{m}$.

Comment: check my edited question.

Comment: again take $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^{2} $ , $f(x) = (x^{3},x^{3})$ is smooth and the projection to the first coordinate is open but yet claim is not true. I think even change the assumption to being homeomorphic would not make your claim true.